# Meaning of 쏙 in 마음에 쏙 들었다

Tags: vocabulary

I came across this word in a sentence like:

마음에 쏙 들었다

It means roughly "to like", however I can't find any meaning for 쏙 apart from some unrelated shrimp creature.

Answer (score 2):

쏙 is one of the mimetic or onomatopoeic adverbs which describe the way something happens or the sound made by it. Korean has a great number of such adverbs.

쏙 describes how something quickly enters into or comes out of an opening or, less frequently, the way a long object such as a plant or a strand of hair is pulled out by the root.
There is also 쑥 with similar meaning but used for something bigger or heavier (vowels ㅗ and ㅏ sound smaller, lighter, and brighter, while ㅜ and ㅓ feel bigger, heavier, and darker).

> - 마음에 **쏙** 들었다 = It/They **completely** suited my heart -> It/They pleased me completely. (figurative use)
> - 고양이가 문틈으로 쏙 들어가 버렸다.
> - 마당 구석에 나 있는 잡초 하나를 쏙/쑥 뽑았다.

There are many such adverbs in Korean.
For example, just by changing the vowel, you get a couple more such words.

> - 테이블 위에 있던 접시들을 싹 다 치웠다. (싹 = completely)
> - 친구는 내 말을 듣고는 씩 웃었다. (씩 = describes making a short but obvious smile)

Comment: Thankyou. I suspected it was an onomatopoeia but I could not find a good reference for it. At least if someone else searches for it there is an answer somewhere now!